# Working with strtotime and MySQL

Tags: php, sql, datetime, strtotime

This works...

```
 mysqli_query
($con, "
    INSERT INTO myDB (id, name, mydate) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', now())
")
```

This doesn't work....

```
 mysqli_query
($con, "
    INSERT INTO myDB (id, name, mydate) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hour')))
")
```

The `mydate` column in MySQL is of `datetime` format.

Any ideas why it's not working? I'm currently using `now()`, but I want it to show the time in my timezone, not the server's timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest storing the date in a variable first.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hour'));
```

If both your MySQL and PHP servers are operating on the same time-zone and have their clocks properly synchronized, you wont have an issue.

and then execute the query like so:

```
mysqli_query($con, "
    INSERT INTO myDB (id, name, mydate) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$date')
")
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I knew it was simple, but it was driving me mad. I did try something like this but it kept writing `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to the database... It turned out that my original date format wasn't correct when I did that (which I fixed for my question).

Comment: Yep I did thanks. It said I had to wait 4 mins before I could accept.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() is not MySQL function, its PHP function, you need to write it for being executes...

```
    "INSERT INTO myDB (id, name, mydate) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hour'))."'
```

Comment: Agreed. You can set a variable ahead of time and use the date and strtotime functions and then plug that into the query.

Comment: How would I do it though? put `$MyDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hour'));` before the SQL and get it to write `'$date'` in the INSERT?